# does having code spread in multiple files decrease performance?

Tags: pygame

Let's say there's a game that I could code in 1 file main.py but I decide to split it in more files like:

main.py
graphics.py
settings.py
interface.py
menu.py

and so on, would the game in turn perform slower because it has to import data from multiple instances instead of just loading all the code at once in a single file?

From my understanding it should make a difference, even if minuscule, is it true?

Comment: Have you tried code analysis? There are services like AppRefactoring or Sourcery AI

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning code into different files is the right thing to do, If the project is small (only a few hundred lines) and you want to focus on finishing it at the moment, you can put all the code in one file, But as your program gets longer, you may want to split it into several files for easier maintenance.

Your guess is basically correct, putting all the code in the same file will improve performance, Python uses [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) to manage different files. You can use the `import` keyword to introduce the contents of other files into the namespace of the current module, so multi-file projects have this extra performance overhead. but this is negligible, and using single file will bring a series of other harm.

Python is an interpreted language, but it will "compile" the source code into bytecode and store it in a disk file (`.pyc`) for faster loading. The granularity of this compilation is a `.py` file. They are stored in a common cache directory (`__pycache__`). The python interpreter checks the modification date of the `.py` source code to determine whether it needs to be recompiled. That is, if you are working on a project with 10,000 files, when you modify a source file and hit the run button, only one file will be recompiled. This greatly reduces recompilation time. When all the source code is in the same file, the compilation time will be longer. This mainly affects development efficiency. (To clarify here, the compiled `.pyc` will only affect the file loading speed rather than the execution efficiency.)

In addition, a single file that is too long will affect the rendering efficiency of a text editor, especially a text editor that uses the error checking function. But its main harm is to reduce code readability and portability.

In conclusion:

1. Single file is better if you focus on completing the current small project.
2. If you are trying to use design patterns, cultivate a good code style, etc., it is good to use multiple files in a small project.
3. In large projects, using a single file to store source code greatly reduces code quality and development efficiency. It brings negligible performance gain. Reducing the number of files has never been one of the options for improving performance.

Comment: Once all the files have been loaded into memory early in the running of the program, the fact that they were loaded from multiple files shouldn't have any impact on the frame-to-frame performance later on, right? So even this minor overhead should be a pay-once load-time cost, not something that would impact framerate?

Comment: @DMGregory It depends on where most of the work is done... And how things line up in the memory. Its possible that having multiple files will be faster then a single file if it changes the position of a heavily used function in the cache in such a way that L1 cache conflicts are avoided. Its possible that it slows it down because that heavily used function has the same L1 cache location as another heavily used function, which causes constant cache misses...

Comment: None of these things are really controllable by you the programmer... So it doesn't really matter

Comment: Although cache line alignment could also be affected by the position of a function *within* a file too, not just multiple files, right? So I don't think we could categorize that level of micro timing difference as being *because of* multiple files in the same way that, say, file loading time is directly attributable to the number of files to load.

Comment: @DMGregory, I don't know what, if any, optimization Python does when it compiles the bytecode, but I once got a 30% speedup for an image loader in C++ just by re-arranging the source code so that the compiler could inline some functions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37202463/950488) on Stack Overflow asked why performance dropped after refactoring related classes into separate files.

In that particular case, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291464/950488) was that the slow down came tight loops that accessed the functions/classes from another module. The additional interpreter lookup added a slight slowdown that accumulated. The is also backed up by an optimization tip in the Python wiki to [consider alternatives to function references in loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...).

I think that it's important to note a couple of things. The first is that this was discovered through benchmarking. If your code is underperforming, use tools like benchmarks & profiling to determine where the problems actually are rather than guessing & changing code that is unrelated to the problem. The second is that the wiki itself says that the suggested solution should be used with caution. Optimizations can make code more difficult to maintain which in turn makes it more difficult to make sure the code is correct.